# Using .NET dll via QT

Tags: c#, c++, .net, qt, dll

I am hardly trying to use Laser Control dll file based on .NET on QT.
I registered dll file on server, made tlb file, and imported it with using command

```
  #import "Litron.Control.CWLasers.tlb" no_namespace named_guids
```

after that, I used this command

```
struct cwDiodeLaserPIV;
cwDiodeLaserPIV Laser=NULL;
CoInitialize(NULL);
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_cwDiodeLaserPIV, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID__cwDiodeLaserPIV, reinterpret_cast<void*>(&Laser));
```

*I added ActiveQT header file also to use CoCreateInstance

when i Check whether this code works with this,

```
if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
{ qDebug()<<"Calling dll is succeded"; }
else
{ qDebug()<<"Calling dll is failed"; }
```

"Calling dll is failed" is come out.
But, When i use same code in Visual Studio C++, "Calling dll is succeded" is come out.
furthermore, even calling dll is succeeded, I couldn't call the function of dll at VS.

Here are some Questions.

I used struct cwDiodeLaserPIV. because in tlh file, cwDiodeLaserPIV is declared with struct command.
but actually, when i see the inner part of dll, cwDiodeLaserPIV was declared with class command.
Why this happen? Can I use it with struct declaration?

When I write down the code at QT, CLSID_ and IID_ part, There were no directory that automatically connected.
On the Other hand, at VS, CLSID_cwDiodeLaserPIV and IID__cwDiodeLaserPIV are automatically found by VS
Say again, at QT, CLSID_cwDiodeLaserPIV and IID__cwDiodeLaserPIV are not found in list of directory that automatically connected when i write down CLSID_ or IID_. Why this happen? Can 't I use this way at QT?

++ I refered https://forum.qt.io/topic/108642/how-to-include-a-com-tlb-library-in-my-c-project/2 and made cpp and header file using dumpcpp. but it seems there aren't enough function in it.

I am such a vanilla on QT and Programming. So, example code would be very helpful
Thanks very much...

Answer (score 0):

`CoCreateInstance` is a sign that you're using COM. This is a technology that allows you to call C++ code from other languages and vice versa. The `struct cwDiodeLaserPIV;` you see in the `.tlh` is a C++ representation of the interface of a COM object. In other languages, other representations may be used. The DLL may be written in C# for instance, which could use the keyword `class`. COM is a glue layer that hides the implementation, but you probably want a second abstraction layer. Pure COM is tricky

The link you found describes a `dumpcpp` tool that's an alternative to the `#import` statement. Both are ways to ease the use of COM, but they indeed work differently. `dumpcpp` knows that it can use Qt library functionality in its implementation.

You can't freely mix the Qt `dumpcpp` approach and the Visual Studio `#import` approach. If you use `dumpcpp`, you must use the interface type that it generates.